# How to setup a cloud run app to receive pub/sub messages in python?

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-run

I'm fairly new to the google cloud platform where I'm trying to set up a python script to do a daily data pull from an external API and store the data in BigQuery. I've got the script setup and, after a lot of research & asking questions on StackOverflow, I managed to deploy it on google cloud run as a flask app.

Essentially, that means that I created two files - `main.py` & `Dockerfile`. The `main.py` file looks like this:

```
# Global libraries
import os
from flask import Flask

# Local libraries
import data_push

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def data():
    return data_push.daily_data_push()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True,host='0.0.0.0',port=int(os.environ.get('PORT', 8080)))
```

and the `Dockerfile` looks like this:

```
# Use the official lightweight Python image.
# https://hub.docker.com/_/python
FROM python:3.6-slim

# Copy local code to the container image.
ENV APP_HOME /app
WORKDIR $APP_HOME
COPY . ./

# Install production dependencies.
RUN pip install Flask gunicorn

# Run the web service on container startup. Here we use the gunicorn
# webserver, with one worker process and 8 threads.
# For environments with multiple CPU cores, increase the number of workers
# to be equal to the cores available.
CMD exec gunicorn --bind :$PORT --workers 1 --threads 8 --timeout 0 app:app
```

where `data_push.daily_data_push()` is the function I need to schedule in order to pull data from the API and store it in BigQuery. Now, based on what I'm reading, I need to first set up the app so that it can talk to pub/sub, and then I can use cloud scheduler to set up a daily schedule to pull the data.

I'm a bit lost on how to set up the script to talk to pub/sub. I'm going through google's documentation on it but I still haven't figured it out. Problem is that I'm a data analyst and both flask & pub/sub are way out my league in terms of expertise.

I'd appreciate your help with either showing me how the script should be set up to talk to pub/sub OR by pointing me towards a source that has the answer.

Comment: If I summarize your design. Your Cloud Run app have one pas `/` that you want to trigger. The path perform an external API call and store the result into BigQuery. Does this part is a problem? Anyway, about the trigger, what do you want to achieve? A periodic trigger? or a trigger when a message is published into PubSub?

Comment: Yes, I want to setup a periodic trigger - once every weekday. The function `data_push.daily_data_push()` triggers the data pull that I want to schedule. How should I set that up?

Comment: Can some one help me with this same question. I want to setup pubsub for cloudrun in the same above case. I don't have a choice of directly scheduling a HTTP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set up a Cloud Scheduler that call an HTTP URL. Put your Cloud Run url in Cloud Scheduler and the correct frequency. PubSub is useless here!

- 0 1 * * * for example, every day at 1am
- 0 1 * * 1-5 for example every working day (Monday to Friday) at 1am

If your Cloud Run is deployed is private mode (no allow-unauthenticated mode), let me know, that require extra configuration.